# Can I upload a file to another Desire2Learn user's locker?

Tags: desire2learn

Can I use a Valence Learning Framework API to upload data into another LE user's locker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you cannot; lockers are explicitly intended to be user-private storage spaces for Learning Environment users. Accordingly, the Valence Learning Framework APIs do not provide a way for calling user to upload data to another user's locker.